How to include build information along with version in springboot?
I'm trying to include build information along with version information in springboot. I've a working local setup that satisfies my requirements. Which looks like this.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <otherstuff></otherstuff>
    <version>1.0.0-${buildNumber}</version>
    <properties>
        <buildNumber>${buildNumber}</buildNumber>
        <otherstuff></otherstuff>
    </properties>
</project>

I build it using mvn clean install -DbuildNumber=5678 . However, it shows a warning that says version is expecting a constant. But it's working fine locallly. But it fails while running in the CI pipeline. I also need it to reflect in the info endpoint we have.
  @GetMapping("/api/app/info")
    AppInfo getAppInfo() {
        return new AppInfo(this.buildProperties.getName(), this.buildProperties.getVersion(),
                this.buildProperties.get("description"), this.buildProperties.get("copyright.info"),
                this.buildProperties.getTime());
    }

What are my options here?
Tried using maven version plugin. Didn't work as expected.

Read the documentation of the spring boot maven plugin: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/maven-plugin/build-info.html#build-info.build-info-goal.parameter-details.output-file

@khmarbaise . That helped.
